# sklearn custom scorer multiple metrics at once

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, scoring

I have a function which returns an `Observation` object with **multiple** scorers
How can I integrate it into a custom sklearn scorer?
I defined it as:

```
class Observation():
    def __init__(self):
        self.statValues = {}
        self.modelName = ""

    def setModelName(self, nameOfModel):
        self.modelName = nameOfModel

    def addStatMetric(self, metricName,metricValue):
        self.statValues[metricName] = metricValue
```

A custom score is defined like:

```
def myAllScore(y_true, y_predicted):
    return Observation
my_scorer = make_scorer(myAllScore)
```

which could look like

```
{   'AUC_R': 0.6892943119440752,
    'Accuracy': 0.9815382629183745,
    'Error rate': 0.018461737081625407,
    'False negative rate': 0.6211453744493393,
    'False positive rate': 0.0002660016625103907,
    'Lift value': 33.346741089307166,
    'Precision J': 0.9772727272727273,
    'Precision N': 0.9815872808592603,
    'Rate of negative predictions': 0.0293063938288739,
    'Rate of positive predictions': 0.011361068973307943,
    'Sensitivity (true positives rate)': 0.3788546255506608,
    'Specificity (true negatives rate)': 0.9997339983374897,
    'f1_R': 0.9905775376404309,
    'kappa': 0.5384745595159575}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short: you cannot.

Long version: scorer **has to** return a single scalar, since it is something that can be used for model selection, and in general - comparing objects. Since there is no such thing as a complete ordering over vector spaces - you cannot return a vector inside a scorer (or dictionary, but from mathematical perspective it might be seen as a vector). Furthermore, even other use cases, like doing cross validation does not support arbitrary structured objects as a return value since they try to call `np.mean` over the list of the values, and this operation is not defined for the list of python dictionaries (which your method returns).

The only thing you can do is to create separate scorer for each of the metrics you have, and use them independently.

Comment: I understand. But would it be possible similar to http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html to obtain several scorings in a single pass?

Comment: you already implemented this, thus I do not understand your question. classification_report is not a scorer, you cannot use it in scorer context.

Comment: Correct. I manually implemented a train test for loop. Howeve,r as I want to try stacking and blending (https://github.com/rushter/heamy)  I started to move to a sklearn pipeline which nicely integrates with the scorer functions.

Answer (score 3):

As a matter of fact it is possible, as described in this fork: [multiscorer](https://github.com/drorata/multiscorer).

For the sake of completeness, here's an example:

```
from multiscorer.multiscorer import MultiScorer

#Scikit's libraries for demonstration
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from numpy import average

scorer = MultiScorer({
  'accuracy': (accuracy_score, {}),
  'precision': (precision_score, {'average': 'macro'})
})

...

cross_val_score(clf, X, target, scoring=scorer )

results = scorer.get_results()

for metric in results.keys():
  print("%s: %.3f" % (metric, average(results[metric])))
```

Comment: This fork is a hacky way that breaks assumption of what scorer is. As it will now return a simply "0.5" for every input instead of an actual score value it cannot be used for model selection or ranking per se. It becomes a much harder problem that now requires nothing of partial orderings etc. It of course depends on the exact use case, if ones goal is just to report said metrics than all that is needed is a simple loop, same way multiscorer is implemented https://github.com/drorata/multiscorer/blob/master/multiscorer/multiscorer.py#L45